# Joint equations of two lines-proof

Tags: linear-algebra

To prove that if $a=\pm b$, then one of the lines represented by $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0$ will make an angle of the same measure the X-axis as the other makes with the Y-axis. Note that it's angle made, not inclination.
If it were inclination, I can prove it as follows(considering acute angle with X for the line making the same angle with Y ($\theta_2$)):

$$\begin{align}
\theta_1 &= 90-\theta_2 \\
\tan\theta_1&=\tan{90-\theta_2} \\
\tan\theta_1&=\cot{\theta_2} \\
\tan\theta_1&=\frac{1}{\cot{\theta_2}} \\
\tan\theta_1\tan\theta_2&=1 \\
m_1m_2&=1
\end{align}$$

also, from the given line, 
$$\begin{align} 
m_1m_2&=\frac{a}{b} \\
m_1m_2&=\frac{\pm b}{b}  \\
m_1m_2&=\pm 1
\end{align}$$

Considering $m_1m_2=+1$, it is somewhat proved.

**How can I prove it using angles with the axes instead of inclinations?**

[image]
Angle made with the axes can be either +ve or -ve, but angle made(by one line) with X-axis=angle made(by second line) with Y-axis in magnitude.

Its angle , in my proof, i considered theta as inclinations(with +ve X-axis)

Comment: A picture would be nice.

Comment: Added the picture

Comment: if $a=b,$ you need $|h| > |a|$ to get two lines. If $|h| = |a| \neq 0$ you get one line.If $|h| < |a|$ you get one point. Finally, if $a=b=h=0$ you get the entire plane, because the equation says $0=0$ and all $(x,y)$ pairs satisfy that.

Comment: You completely missed the question. And where does it say that $0=0$?